# Kendo UI Combobox Web API OData Bug

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, combobox, kendo-ui, odata

I'm using a Kendo UI Combobox tied to an OData v4 Web API service.  I've tackled all the common WebAPI/OData problems and have the same service working perfectly with a Kendo UI Grid, but the Combo box throws the following error after doing this

1. Combobox binds successfully
2. Filter the combo box
3. Select a value
4. Combobox selection changes
5. Click the down error on the combobox to select something else - error happens here with a 400 from the service.

> "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The value for OData
>   query '$filter' cannot be empty"

I'd like either the filter to be dropped or to use the previous filter.  Here's the current code:

```
 $("#orders").kendoDropDownList({

      dataTextField: "SuName",
      dataValueField: "SuID",
      filter: "contains",
      virtual: {
          itemHeight: 26,
          valueMapper: function (options) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "*url*",
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: convertValues(options.value),
                  success: function (data) {
                      options.success(data);
                  }
              })
          }
      },
      height: 520,
      dataSource: {
          type: 'odata-v4',
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url: "*url*",
                  dataType: "json"
              }
          },
          schema: {
              model: {
                  fields: {
                      SuID: { type: "number" },
                      SuName: { type: "string" },
                  }
              }
          },
          pageSize: 80,
          serverPaging: true,
          serverFiltering: true
      }
  });
```

Comment: Any code you can give to provide an example of this 'bug' so that it can be reproduced with the least amount of guessing by us? Maybe a jsfiddle or by using the snippet editor? You could provide an example with the default connections available on the telerik code example website...

Comment: The default service URL's wont work to reproduce the error since they don't use Web API OData v4 - but I added some code so you can see how I setup the combobox

Comment: You can expand the transport read functionality to check what parameters are being send, you could check out one of the options offered here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read or you could play around with the convertValues(options.value) method to see what you could do (it's been a while since i used Kendo and i'm not sure which steps are comming when)